# From CST to CDT in R

Tags: r, datetime

Here is my example:

```
date_test <- ISOdate(2012,12,1)
attr(date_test, "tzone") <- "America/Chicago"
```

It gives me time in CST. How do I convert it to CDT? I am reading through documentation and it takes forever.

Comment: Why would you want to convert to CDT when CDT was observed between March 11th and November 4th in 2012 (https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/chicago?year=2012)? Just curious!

Comment: My data came from SQL as string, I convert it with `as.POSIXct` and got back CDT, all of my data is in 2017. Now I need to compare to some fixed date and when I create manually date I get back CST (after setting timezone). Still confused...

Comment: or perhaps drop the timezone altogether with as.Date(strftime(df$your_variable, format = '%Y-%m-%d')) and then try as.POSIXct(df$your_variable, tz = "CDT")

Comment: I agree with @ccapizzano however, this could be needed for a DateTime on November 4th 2012 because 1:00-2:00 AM occurs twice that day.